# How to make an div divided into four parts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.menu_box{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 70vh;
    height: 60vh;
}
.menu_box_header{
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.menu_options{
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="menu_box">
    <div class="menu_box_header">
    </div>
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6">part1</div>
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6">part2</div>
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6">part3</div>
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6">part4</div>
</div>
```

And here is the expected result:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: So you simply want to add some height?

Comment: already you got it right?

Comment: @MatthiasS. I can add a constant height. But the point is, the height changes and it should be dynamic

Comment: why don't you use CSS flexbox/grid to achieve this? It would be much convenient.

Comment: Agreed, flexbox is the easiest way to achieve this and it's supported from IE10+ (if you need IE9 support you'd need to use a polyfill, even then I'd still go with flexbox over possible alternatives).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a flexbox approach - I added an inner container so that the lower boxes will fill the remaining space dynamically

```css
.menu_box {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 70vh;
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* stack inner boxes vertically */
}

.menu_box_body {
  flex-grow: 1;    /* make this flex so 4 boxes will fill it equally */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:100%;
}

.menu_box_header {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu_options {
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  display:flex;               /* use flex for centring */
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="menu_box">
  <div class="menu_box_header">
  </div>
  <div class="menu_box_body">
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6">part1</div>
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6">part2</div>
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6">part3</div>
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6">part4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now I'm trying to make the value of each section center (vertically). Any idea how can I do that? Noted that `vertical-align: middle` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you can wrap your columns in a row ( standard bootstrap ), and style that row with `display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap` and add `height:calc(100% - 55px)` where `55px` = `45px` ( height of header ) + `10px` ( margin-bottom of header) . And you will get 4 columns equal in height

```css
.menu_box {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 70vh;
  height: 60vh;
  
}
.row-eq-height{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:calc(100% - 55px)
}
.menu_box_header {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu_options {
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="menu_box">
  <div class="menu_box_header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="row-eq-height">


    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6">part1</div>
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6">part2</div>
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6">part3</div>
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6">part4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```